# Why wont my meteor each function work?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am making a web application through meteor, and recently I have set up a mongo database on it.  I am now trying to display the documents through an each function with this code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  gameTabs: function(){
    return PopularGames.find();
  }
});
```

and then implementing it in the html with:

```
{{#each gameTabs}}
  {{>popularGames}}
{{/each}}
```

It wont display the results, and when I check the chrome console, it appears that there are no documents in the database at all, even though my terminal where I am running the db says there are documents in it. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you publishing the documents to the client?
If you are just starting out, autopublish package might be helpful for you.
You can add it using :

```
meteor add autopublish
```

Or try setting up the pub/subs as given [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe)